# ManyToMany with cascade all only cascading one way

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, cascade

I have 2 entities:
1) User
2) Department.

each contains a SET of the other since the relationship between them is manyToMany,

I marked (CascadeType.ALL) on the user entity and the department entity and when i do :

```
userX.getDepartments.remove(departmentX);
save(userX);
```

it works like intended - it actually implies that

```
departmentX.getUsers.contains(userX) == false.
```

is called implicitly.

BUT ,  when i do

```
departmentY.getUsers.remove(userX);
save(departmentY);
```

it doesn't cascade! 
meaning - i can do

```
userX.getDepartments.contains(departmentY) == true
```

any ideas why the cascade all works only one way?
is there a solution?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The cascade is irrelevant to what you're doing. Cascading means: when I save X, also save Y.

You have a ManyToMany bidirectional association. The owner side of the asociation is User. This means that every change to the `User.departments` collection will be saved into the database. The other side (`Department.users`) is the inverse side. This means that every change to `Department.users` will be ignored by Hibernate.

It's YOUR responsibility to xecute the operations in the owner side and, preferrably, to maintain both sides of the association in a coherent state: when a user is removed from a department, the department should also be removed from the user, and vice-versa. Hibernate doesn't care if both sides are in a coherent state though: it persists the state of the owner side of the association (the one which doesn't have a `mappedBy` attribute)

Comment: Now i'm pretty reluctant to use this mechanism and make my code dirty with a lot of dao calls for crud operations of departments when i do it for users...